# Will These Bike Racks Fit a 2002 Citroen Berlingo?

Tags: rack, car-rack

Could someone please advise me as to whether either (or both!) of the following bike racks will fit on the back of a 2002 Citroen Berlingo?

> [3 Carrier with Clips](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=351040656435&ssPageName=ADME:X:RTQ:GB:1123)
>
> [2 Carrier without Clips](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-3-BICYCLE-CARRIER-CAR-RACK-BIKE-CYCLE-UNIVERSAL-FITS-MOST-CARS-REAR-MOUNT-/280930241759)

Please note: these are links to eBay (UK) listings - I realise that this is irregular, but I couldn't actually find the manufacturer's website for them!

They are both strap-mounted, not tow-bar mounted; I do not have a tow-bar. Please note that it is a *van* and so has a *vertical* rear, not like a saloon/hatchback/estate, but to a smaller degree with an estate.

I am looking to mount a road/racing bike and a mountain bike on it. I would prefer the 3 Carrier with clips, since, well, it holds three and has clips (!), but if it doesn't fit and the other one does, then the other one will do fine. :)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm looking at the photos in your second link, looks like a good way to break off a rear spoiler.

Comment: There isn't much of a rear spoiler on a 2002 Citroen Berlingo! =P

Answer (score 1):

Those style of racks are pretty versitile, I would be surprised if they do not fit.

The only problem may be that as you Citroen has a near verticle rear, the bikes may sit further out from the rear than needed, depending on rack design and adjustments. This puts weight further behind the rear wheels affecting handling. I used a Rhode version of these regularly, but when I need to carry 3 or more bikes I use my old 4x4 (Isuzu Bighorn, Opel/Vauxhall Monterey/ GMC Trooper depending where in the world you live) and a towbar mounted rack. Even that car is affected by the weight of 3 bikes hanging off the rear end.

I would hesitate to put too much weight on such a rack, and I would invest in a reputable brand if the bikes are worth a lot, but I have seen racks like these loaded with 4 mountain bikes. Think about what happens if the rack fails - I had a mate who managed a large bike shop, he often had customers buying new bikes after they fell off racks. One customer purchased 4 new bikes after the rack fell off at 100km/h with a logging truck following him.

If you do go ahead with one of these be aware of the common failure modes-  the straps on some models often loosen over hours of driving - so long trips pay speacial attention. Also the ones with the rubber clips that hold the bike, do not trust the rubber. Many internet reviews discuss straps breaking and bikes falling on the road. I always use an independent tie down (bungies are fast and effective), maybe I am paranoid. Also many people discuss problems at speeds like 70MPH - think of the wind pressure of a bike movign sideways at 70mph, even on the back of a car its significant (My car uses 2litre/100km more petrol carrying bikes, all of that is drag caused by the bike....).

Comment: Thank you for your response. (I'm in the UK, so either an Isuzu or a Vauxhall! Also means not many logging trucks, but thanks for the advice!)

Comment: The road/racing bike is a proper one so although valuable, pretty light. The mountain bike isn't a downhill one (an only mountain/hybrid) and is fairly heavy (could put that one closest). I don't *need* to put the (heavier) mountain bike on, but really want the (lighter) racing bike on there.
I shall try one of them and let you know whether it works. Which one would you recommend for likelihood of fitting, or pretty much the same for either?

Comment: PS - when I have 15+ reputation I'll upvote your response. I'll mark it as accepted later, but just hoping for a few more opinions first. :) [I have over 100 rep on the maths part - shame it doesn't carry over!]

Comment: The log truck story alone is worth the price of admission!

Comment: Whenever loading a vehicle it's worth an independent strap to a solid part.  A [kayak cable lock](http://www.hbcanoekayak.co.uk/transport-security/448-playboater-rackguard.html) is designed for boats on the roof but would work for bikes on the back.  It passes through the doors so provides a level of safety retention as well as security.  I used to use a long cable lock to the towing eye and D-lock the bikes together. (also in response to @Batman's comments re security)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed this comment until just now! Thank you for your comment: I shall certainly be careful with security as I have a racing bike so quite expensive! :)

Comment: I got one of the three-carriers. It was a touch tricky/fiddly to get on due to the swinging doors, but it does fit fine. Thank you everyone for your help! Most appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you have to try a rack or check the manufacturer's compatibility list in order to see if it fits. The latter is not a sure option though - I once purchased a Thule rack which wouldn't clear the lip spoiler on my car, despite it being listed in the Thule compatibility list. It turns out that the models they test for compatibility on are the very base model (of which only the base manual lacks the lip spoiler), and I had to return the rack.

Also, when you buy a rack, make sure its of good quality. I'd be wary of putting a thousand dollars of bicycles on a 40 dollar rack. Also, note that racks aren't very secure when the vehicle is parked, so if possible, valuable bicycles should be stored inside the vehicle rather than outside (there are small locks which some rack manufacturers sell, but you can usually just take the rack itself if you really wanted to if its the kind that goes over the trunk - its a bit more work for the trailer hitch kind, but still feasible).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I need the rack because the inside of the van will be full! I'll probably only put one or two bikes on, worth about £500. I'll use bike locks on them as well and try not to leave it unmanned. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar rack (halfords branded) to those 2 (they use the same basic setup)  on an estate with a very steep tailgate, and can't see any reason why it wouldn't fit a Berlingo (which has a tailgate I presume, swing doors might be an issue).

I did tend to set it up with the bottom of the rack on the rear bumper, but I didn't have to, it was just that the lowest hooks had nowhere to go except underneath the car.  You may have a similar issue, which would mean you can't open the tailgate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - very helpful. It's a Berlingo Box Van, not MPV, so it has swinging doors. Should still work though?

Comment: Might be tricky.  If there's enough clearance to get the hooks over the doors with them shut it would be fine, but if you have to open the doors to get the hooks over, then shut the doors before tightening the straps it would be fiddly.  I'd be looking at the Fiamma carry-bike range  (that's what I've got on my Transit).  Mine is drilled through the doors but there are clamp-on versions meant for transporters with doors.  They attach to 1 door and you can open the doors.

Comment: The back would be full of stuff, so I wouldn't be able to tighten from the inside... would be fiddly, but possible?

Comment: ...[like this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Fiamma-2-Bike-Rack-For-VW-T5-Twin-Rear-Doors-No-Drilling-Carry-up-to-2-Bikes-/271444388629) -- clearly versatile as it's meant for twin doors but they've put it on a tailgate.  Admittedly it's more expensive, and unrealistic for infrequent use, but it's much more solid.  I think the dimensions are online

Comment: @SmileySam the straps tighten from the outside so that wouldn't be an issue.  Maybe masking tape to keep the straps under control while you shut the doors -- iff you can't get the hooks over with the doors shut - I've had cars where you could and cars where you couldn't and IME vans have bigger clearances on the door seals than cars.

Comment: I would only use it a couple of times a year, so I was thinking more £25 not £155! Thank you for the advise though.
I'll try one of the cheaper ones and see how it goes. :)

Comment: @SmileySam good plan, the universal ones also pop up 2nd hand all the time, unlikely the Fiammas, so it's easy to ebay-hire one.

Comment: It was a touch tricky/fiddly to get on due to the swinging doors, but it does fit fine. Thank you everyone for your help! Most appreciated! :)